# Right justify button in vuetify

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I'd like the top of my page to have a title on the left and a button on the right, then a light ruler line underneath.

Here's what I am trying...

```
<span class="title">Morticia & Gomez Addams</span>
<v-btn @click="save()">Save</v-btn> 
<v-divider class="pb-3"></v-divider>
```

But here's what it produces... the button is not right justified

[image]

I thought `v-spacer` was the way to make this work, but that gives me a new line instead.

```
<span class="title">Morticia & Gomez Addams</span>
<v-spacer></v-spacer>
<!-- button, etc --!>
```

[image]

I've also tried "alignment helpers"...

```
<!-- etc. --!>
<span class="text-xs-right"><v-btn @click="save()">Save</v-btn></span>
<!-- etc. --!>
```

I'd prefer to use the vuetify built-in styles, but I'll appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd happily accept a less verbose answer, but the only way I could get it done was by tricking `v-card` into what I wanted...

```
<v-card color="transparent" class="elevation-0">
  <v-toolbar color="transparent" class="elevation-0">
    <span class="title">Morticia & Gomez Addams</span>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn @click="save()" small>Save</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar>
  <v-divider class="pb-3"></v-divider>
</v-card>
```